# SELECT privilege granted through direct grant and through a role

Tags: oracle, plsql, privileges

I have the SELECT privilege granted through an Oracle role and I can see data in particular table. (My acc has (or belongs to) the role which has granted SELECT prvilege for particular table).

But in order to make the VIEW or PROCEDURE which would SELECT the data from the same table I must have SELECT privilege granted directly to my acc!

Why's that? Why SELECT grant through a role is not sufficient enough?

Comment: Because Oracle decided long ago that this is a good thing. Why they decided that only Oracle can answer.

Comment: http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/faq/plsql_privs.html

Answer (score 0):

Roles are switched off inside PL/SQL procedures. You can simulate what you see without your roles with

```
SET ROLE NONE;
```

You can see your current roles with

```
SELECT * FROM session_roles;
```

To switch them back on:

```
SET ROLE ALL;
```

I don't know if Oracle ever gave a reason why roles are switched off. I always assumed it's to increas performance. Before every execution it is checked if you have access to all the tables in a query. If you allow roles, which can be granted to other roles, you need quite a complex tree/graph query to find out if access is ok. With direct privileges only, this has linear complexity.

Comment: Explained here: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=procedures-roles-and-grants Basically roles are transient and can be enabled, disabled, password-protected etc, but the compiler needs to know exactly where it stands at compilation time.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson thanks for the link! I like Tom's distinction "Roles are for ... end users", while direct privs are for application objects.